# How to find out that a refrence type property changed in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have  a UserControl like this:

```
 <Button Grid.Row="1" X:Name="ChangeButton" Click="ChangeButton_Click">Change</Button>
```

My UserControl CodeBehind:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPersonProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedPerson", typeof(PersonModel), typeof(MyControl),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
     {
         DefaultValue=null,
         BindsTwoWayByDefault = true

     });

    public PersonModel SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return (PersonModel)GetValue(SelectedPersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedPersonProperty, value);}
    }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextValue", typeof(string), typeof(NumericTextBox),
        new  FrameworkPropertyMetadata{
                BindsTwoWayByDefault=true

                });

    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty); }
        set { 
            SetValue(TextValueProperty, value);

        }
    }
public MyControl(){
        SelectedPerson = new PersonModel();

}
 private void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextValue="Hello";
        SelectedPerson.Age = 12;
        SelectedPerson.FirstName = "AA";
        SelectedPerson.LastName = "BB";

    }
```

In my MainView  Xaml Code i have :

```
<UC:MyControl SelectedPerson="{Binding Person}" TextValue="{Binding Path=Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></UC:MyControl>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="1"  Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding Path=Person.Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

MainViewModel Code:

```
     PersonModel person
     public PersonModel Person { 
            get { return _person; }
            set
            {

                if (_person!= value)//i set a breakpoint here
                {
                    _person= value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Person ");
                }
            }
 }
   string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)//i set a breakpoint here.when TextValue changed this breakepoint actived
            {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

when i click on ChangeButton in my user control the selectedperson in usercontrol changed and my Textbox in my view show Name like  "AA".but my breake point in viewmode is not actived.how can i find out that when my Person in viewmode changed?

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged inside the PersonModel and and set a break point on the property that you change instead of the entire Person object property. Like so

```
class PersonModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value; <---- set breakpoint here
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }
}
```

You can then listen to changes in personmodel class like so:

```
myParentObject.Person.PropertyChanged += (sender,e)=>
{
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: @Hassan Khan I need that findout it in my viewmodel.i edit my question.when TextValue changed my Name in viewmode breakepoint actived but why selectedperson changed  the person breakepoint in view model not active?

Answer (score 1):

To hit breakpoint for the Person setter you need to update ChangeButton_Click as following:

```
private void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextValue="Hello";
        PersonModel newPerson = new PersonModel();
        newPerson.Age = 12;
        newPerson.FirstName = "AA";
        newPerson.LastName = "BB";
        SelectedPerson = newPerson;
    }
```

What you were doing was just modifying properties on existing PersonModel object. This way you will not hit breakpoint at PersonModel object setter but you will hit breakpoint on properties setter inside PersonModel class. By modifying code as above you will hit you breakpoint.